# Android. Xml. How to write data in xml (not in SD card).

Tags: android, xml

I'm new to android xml data storage. I have one `details.xml` file for saving the users name and password. I want to write the users name string and password string to my `details.xml` file. How do I write the data in XML? Where do I have to add that file? How to call that file programmatically? I seem to be able to read but not to write XML. Kindly guide me some programing examples. I've found [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) about android data-storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've read the information at the link, you know that there are basically two places where you can store a file: external and internal storage. Since, as you've mentioned, external storage is not suitable for you, you can use internal storage.

The link you provided contains [information about writing to internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). In short, you will have to use `Context.openFileOutput(String name, int mode)`.